# Summation of infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm taking a single-variable calculus course and asked to calculate
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\pi^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
So the $k=0$ term looks like
$$(-1)^0 \frac{\pi^{2(0)}}{(2(0)!)}=\frac{1}{0!}$$
but $\frac{1}{0!}$ is not a number, so it appears I've made a mistake in my calculation.

Comment: By definition, 0! = 1, so it is a number.

Comment: And you are just asked to compute $\cos(\pi)=-1$.

Comment: why do you " .. let $k=0$ " and keep the summation ? $k$ is either a parameter in the summands and the **index** of summation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a natural convention, $0!=1$.

This is coherent, as for $n>1$,

$$n!=n\cdot(n-1)!,$$ or

$$(n-1)!=\frac{n!}n,$$

hence we extend to $n=1$ with

$$0!=\frac{1!}1.$$

For the same reason $(-1)!$ and all the negatives are undefined.

---

It is also customary to define the product of no factor as $1$, just like the sum of no term is defined to be $0$.

---

You may be interested to know that one can extend the factorial to non-integers, and here is a plot of the standard extension:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to YvesDaoust's answer, see the [Taylor expansion of cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) around $0$:

$$\cos(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

So in essence, you are calculating

$$\cos(\pi)=-1$$